# Missing Google gradle plugins in Gradle plugin portal?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I was trying to migrate `build.gradle` files to use Kotlin DSL. [Using the `plugins` block instead of `apply` (legacy, apparently)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html#applying_plugins) doesn't seem to be as straightforward as suggested. Since `"com.google.firebase.appdistribution"`, `"com.google.firebase.crashlytics"`, and `"com.google.gms.google-services"` are missing in the Gradle [plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) (?). Can I not use them in the plugin block? I tried [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories) but it didn't seem to work. Also, why are they missing? I still don't quite understand how this works so please bear with me.